# Mouseover event firing up as soon as I drag the mouse on the map

Tags: javascript, events, leaflet, mouseover

I was dealing with Leaflet and having issue with mouseover event.
What I want is to show a tooltip info when I move the hover and stop on the map.
However, my implementation is firing up as soon as I open the map. It totally makes sense how it works in my case but I cannot find a way to show tooltip when "mouseover" on specific place on the map. Also, it should be removable when mouseout and show tooltip again when mouseover.
Here is my code:

```
   mymap.on('click', function(e){
  var lt = String(e.latlng.lat),
  lg = String(e.latlng.lng);

  const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const url='http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?lat='+lt+'&lng='+lg+'&username=aziyatali';
  Http.open("GET", url);
  Http.send();

 Http.onreadystatechange = (ev) => {
  var countryData = JSON.parse(Http.responseText);
  console.log(countryData);
  var countryName = countryData.geonames[0].countryName;
  console.log("My requestL ", countryName);
  var popup = L.popup()
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .setContent(countryName)
    .openOn(mymap);
}
});
```

Currently, it is showing the current country name when I click on the specific part of the map. It get the latlng of the current event and gets country name via *geonamesAPI*

[link to code](http://jsfiddle.net/j8769vwr/#&togetherjs=nfSB5VCu5M)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a "mousemove - end - listener".

```
var timeout = null;
mymap.on('mousemove', function(e){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(()=>{runScript(e)},200);
});

function runScript(e){
  var lt = String(e.latlng.lat),
  lg = String(e.latlng.lng);

  const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const url='http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?lat='+lt+'&lng='+lg+'&username=aziyatali';
  Http.open("GET", url);
  Http.send();

  Http.onreadystatechange = (ev) => {
    var countryData = JSON.parse(Http.responseText);
    console.log(countryData);
    var countryName = countryData.geonames[0].countryName;
    console.log("My requestL ", countryName);
    var popup = L.popup()
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .setContent(countryName)
    .openOn(mymap);
  }
}
```

Everytime the mousemove event is called, the timeout is reset and restartet. If it is not cleared anymore -> mouse stops you can execute the script.

http://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/ot4bq6Lx/